# How can I exclude some images from being preloaded

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, animated-gif, preloader

I really couldn't find an answer to this one.

I have a preloader for a website. On the website there's a slideshow that includes 10mb animated gifs.

Is there a way to exclude some of the gifs from being preloaded so that the website itself doesn't wait for a gif that won't show at the beginning of the slideshow anyway?
Thanks!

This is my preloader:

HTML:

```
<!-- Preloader -->
<div id="preloader">
 <div id="status">
   <div class="parent">
     <div class="child">
       <p class="small">loading</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#preloader { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; background:#000; z-index:9999; }
#status { z-index:28; position:absolute; color:#fff; top:50%; height:280px; width:100%; margin-top:-140px; }
/* horizontal centering */
.parent {width:280px; margin:0px auto; position:relative; height:280px; z-index:11}
.child {text-align:center;}
/* vertical centering */
.parent {display: table}
.child {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; padding:0 50px; }
.child span { text-transform:uppercase; }
```

preloader.js:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { 
"use strict";
        jQuery("#status").fadeOut(350); // will first fade out the loading animation
        jQuery("#preloader").delay(350).fadeOut(200); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
    });
```

EDIT:
I found the following at [This website](http://andydavies.me/blog/2013/10/22/how-the-browser-pre-loader-makes-pages-load-faster/)

I still don't know how to use it though. Any hints? would you say this could be what I'm looking for? thanks.

> Influencing the pre-loader
>
> Currently there are limited ways we can influence the pre-loader’s priorities (hiding resources using javascript is one), but the W3C Resource Priorities spec proposes two attributes to help signal our intent.
>
> lazyload : resource should not be downloaded until other resources that aren’t marked lazyload have started downloading
>
> postpone : resource must not be downloaded until it’s visible to the user i.e. within the viewport and display is not none.
>
> Although I’m not sure how easy it is to polyfill, perhaps postpone might enable a simple way of implementing responsive images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/)
It progressively loads the images.

A programmer I know wrote this:

"You need to adapt the div-Block in your html file with the class "cycle-slideshow"
and add the following attributes to the tag:

```
  data-cycle-loader=true
  data-cycle-progressive="#slideshow-images"
```

Your div-Tag should only contain one image now, the first one. All other images
go on the list. The "slideshow-images" is an id (denoted by the # in front of it)
of a list where you list all the images you want your slideshow to show and load
progressively. It has the following form:

```
  <script id="slideshow-images" type="text/cycle">
  [
    "<img src='http://malsup.github.io/images/beach2.jpg'>",
    "<img src='http://malsup.github.io/images/beach3.jpg'>",
    ...
    "<img src='http://malsup.github.io/images/beach9.jpg'>"
  ]
  </script>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { 
"use strict";
    jQuery("#status").fadeOut(350); // will first fade out the loading animation
    jQuery("#preloader").delay(350).fadeOut(200); // will fade out the white DIV that     covers the website.
    $('.somewhere').append("/*your slide gif code here*/"); // this will load after everything else is loaded. and make sure you put your script right before closing </body> tag, so it will load everything on the page 1st. it will increase you page load. 
});
```

and remove your slide IMG html, and move it inside your .load function.

Comment: It's stuck at preload...I should've posted more info before. This is what I have in my html          <div class="element  clearfix col2-3 home">
    <div id="slideshow-container">
      <div id="slideshow">
        <div id="box1"><img src="images/about04.jpg"></div>

  </div>
    </div>

Comment: AGAIN (first time using these comments!) HTML<br/>      `<div class="element  clearfix col2-3 home">
<div id="slideshow-container">
  <div id="slideshow">
    <div id="box1"><img src="images/about04.jpg"></div>

  </div>
</div>`

Comment: JS: `jQuery(window).load(function() { 
"use strict";
   jQuery("#status").fadeOut(350); // will first fade out the loading animation
   jQuery("#preloader").delay(350).fadeOut(200); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
$(".slideshow").append("<div id="box1"><img src="images/organix.gif">);
$(".slideshow").append(<div id="box1"><img src="images/house.gif">);
  });`

Comment: Was this what you meant?

Comment: I added comment to my answer, if you put your script right before the </body> tag, you make sure slide-less .html file got loaded, and than after everything is loaded you add-in the img - heavy slide. so the user get to see all other content 1st.

Comment: instead using .append() you can use .attr() to set the img src path.  same concept.